# ZF2: How to set form elements to be ignored?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

Somehow I can't get Form Elements in Zend Framework 2 to be ignored.

All of this doesn't seem to work:

```php
$this->add(array(
  'name' => 'submit',
  'ignore' => TRUE,
  'attributes' => array(
    'type'  => 'submit',
    'value' => 'Go!',
    'id' => 'submitbutton',
    'ignore' => TRUE
),
'options' => array(
  'ignore' => TRUE
)
));
```

This is how it *used to* work in Zend Framework1:

```php
//Zend Framework 1
$this->addElement(
  'submit',
  'login',
  array(
   'ignore' => true,
   'label' => 'Login'
    )
);
```

**EDIT:

Why would I need the option "ignore"?**
Let's say your form has a submit button. With normal PHP, something like `$_POST` will also list your submit button. Zend 1 has the useful options `setIgnore($flag)` and `getIgnore()` to exclude such elements. `$form->getValues()` (after validation) would exclude all elements with flag 'ignore' set to `TRUE`. See [ZF1 manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.elements.html#zend.form.elements.methods).

Comment: What do you mean by ignore. And what purpose would it be to ignore a submit element? Do you mean exclude from validation? Do you mean to allow empty values? Your question isn't really straight forward.

Comment: @Sam: Thanks for your hint. I thought "Zend-Frameworkers" would know what I mean. ;) I edited my orig. post to clarify.

Comment: As far as i know, ZF2 has no such feature and personally i would consider this a good thing as it's quite useless, too. If you do not need any of the POST-Data, then simply don't use it. There's no real need to not have it at all. Since you set the Form-Data using `$form->setData($request->getPost())` you could simply pot the `getPost()` into a variable and then `unset($postData['submit'])` or so...

Comment: I have a situation where there is a form element which changes other hidden form elements via JavaScript. The form element is purely aesthetic, so I do not need it POSTed to the server. In this case, it would be useful to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out about [inputfilters](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.input-filter.intro.html)

My use is like that:

1. create your form
2. create a filter
3. in controller use that

   ```
   $form = new BasicForm();
   $form->setInputFilter(new BasicFilter());
   ```

About the filter, you can do this:
   $factory = new InputFactory();

```
    $this->add($factory->createInput(array(
        'name' => 'birthday',
        'required' => false,
        'allowEmpty' => true,));
```

Comment: This is not the solution (at least when working with the form's bind() method), additionally allowEmpty is deprecated since ZF2 2.4.8

Answer (score 0):

```
$form->setValidationGroup('email', 'password');
$form->setData($data);
if ($form->isValid()) {
    // Contains only the "email" and "password" values
    $data = $form->getData();
}
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#validation-groups

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for

```
'options' => array(
    'exclude' => true,
),
```